# Solzhenitsyn's History of Russian Jews

Tags: political-history, russia, jews

I was looking for some comprehensive histories of Jews in Russia, when I came across Aleksander Solzhenitsyn's [*Two Hundred Years Together*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Hundred_Years_Together). I had no idea that this book even existed, and am disappointed that it is not available in English translation.

The usual people (Daily Stormer, Occidental Observer, etc) and a variety of supposedly left-leaning, Holocaust-denying and Jew-hating commenters on Amazon have all decided that the reason it doesn't exist in translation is because it is being suppressed. Given the prevalence of trash antisemitism that exists in English, I highly doubt that something written by so eloquent and expressive a writer as Solzhenitsyn would be deliberately withdrawn from the public, but there's no arguing with some people.

Are there any Russian speakers here (or French or German speakers, since it was translated into *those* languages) who have read this book and who can comment on the nature of its content? How historically reliable is it? How incendiary is it? And are there any plans for a proper English translation? (I say "proper" because the websites I referenced earlier are compiling translations of their own, but I have good reason to suspect they are incorporating [passages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Solzhenitsyn#On_Russia_and_the_Jews) that Solzhenitsyn himself disavowed.)

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to paint left leaning people as Holocaust deniers. Despite a lot of troubling antisemitism on the left, full blown Holocaust denial is a far right gig ('left leaning' social democrats were liable to be joining to Jews in the ovens after all)

Comment: I agree, @NeMo. That's what I meant by "supposedly" left-leaning.

Comment: I am not quite sure what kind of an answer you are expecting. Solzhenitsyn is an excellent writer, in the tradition of 19th century realism, but not a good historian. He is reliable in the sense that he will not invent quotes, but he is not reliable in the sense that once he either is unaware of historic sources contradicting some of the central themes of his book or  simply does not care. His book is not  incendiary (as some other "publications" you mention), but is just not that good if you treat it as a historic research monograph.

Comment: Unfortunately, the detailed critique of his writing by professional historians is either behind the paywall or is in Russian. Google translate will give you a reasonably good approximation of what Petrovsky-Shtern says here: http://magazines.russ.ru/nz/2001/4/shtern.html. Petrovsky-Shtern also has a shorter English version of his review here: “On Solzhenitsyn’s ‘Middle Path,’” Polin, no. 18 (2005), 381-392. Polin is published by Institute for Polish-Jewish Studies (Oxford). Your library might have it (my university library does); or  use the interlibrary loan to get it.

Comment: Very helpful, @MoisheCohen - thank you. My library does have that, and I'll give it a read!

Comment: Incidentally, you should check if there is a Hebrew translation. As far as I am concerned, the only way to translate and publish it responsibly is by supplementing the translation with in-depth critical analysis by a professional historian (of Jewish history in Russia), like Petrovsky-Shtern, which would result in something like 2000 page-long 4-volume book. I cannot imagine any publisher publishing such a thing. Who and how published the German and French translations I do not know.

Comment: One more thing: If you just want to quote a fragment from the book, you can use: Mahoney, Daniel J.; Solzhenitsyn, Aleksandr Isaevich; Edward L. Beach Jr (2009). The Solzhenitsyn Reader: New and Essential Writings, 1947–2005. Lanham, MD: Intercollegiate Studies Institute; pages 488–507.

Comment: @NeMo: Homosexuals were also persecuted and exterminated by Nazis in the very same ovens; does this mean that traditionally religious forms of Judaism either condone or encourage homosexuality ? Sharing a common enemy does not necessarily make two parties friends, except perhaps conjecturally (e.g., Russia and the US between WWII and the McCarthy era). During communism, in both Russia and Romania, homosexuality was outlawed; that both communists and homosexuals once shared a common threat to their existence did not seem to matter all that much to the far-left authorities.

Comment: Not really sure where you're going with that, mate. I didn't say anything about Jewish perspectives on homosexuality. And in any case don't know what that has to do with the left-right divide and holocaust denial.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am a Russian speaker who read the book, and many reviews of this book. Most reviews label it as anti-semitic. Its main point is to justify or acquit all Russian actions with respect to the Jews. And to shift the blame on the Jews whenever he can. I would not recommend this as a book on the history of Jews in Russia. On my opinion, the book is of interest only from the point of view of history of the Russian chauvinist thought.

For the early (before the mid 19th century) history, I recommend Leskov, Jews in Russia (there is an English translation). I intentionally choose a "genuine Russian" author (and quite famous and respected), who is not related in any way to the Jews.

Comment: Thank you, Alex (and +1). Do you know if anybody is preparing a translation of it into English? Even if it is unreliable, it seems significant to me as something representing Solzhenitsyn's view. I'd like to be able to quote it.

Comment: @Shimon bM: No, I am not aware of any plans to translate it.

Comment: @ShimonbM: given this answer, I cannot imagine why would anyone bother translating the book.

Comment: So its being "suppressed" in roughly the same manner that [The Terror of Tiny Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terror_of_Tiny_Town) is being suppressed by Netflix.

Comment: @T.E.D. I strongly disagree. On my opinion, there is simply nobody to translate it. This is a huge book, a lot of work, and hard to find any strongly interested Western publisher. Most of the antisemitic rubbish (and other rubbish, which is abundant in Russian) is not translated.

Comment: Sometimes the publishers send me Russian books to referee, with the question "to translate them or not". In this particular case I would recommend "not to translate". And I suppose most of the people who read the book will answer the same. So much about "suppression". If you wish to translate it, go ahead. But I predict poor sales.

Comment: @Alex - Sounds more like you are agreeing with me then.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yes, perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted to say. Should the SECOND occurrence of "suppressed" in your comment be in quotation marks? (I am not familiar with the story of The terror of Tiny Town "suppression").

Comment: @Alex - Sorry. There may be a language/cultural barrier here? Terror of Tiny Town is a movie famous for being one of the consensus candidates for worst movie ever made. It is also fairly objectionable to some people for being one big rolling short-person joke (A western with an all-midget cast). Almost nobody would want to see if it were available on Netflix, so it likely wouldn't be worth the expense and disk space it would take for them to serve it. Indirectly the controversial content certainly contributes to that, but calling that "suppression" would be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Replace your example with "So its being *suppressed*  in roughly  the same manner as the professional mathematical community *suppresses* countless *proofs* of  squaring of the circle". Then we all will be on the same page. (Alex is a well-regarded professional mathematician.)

Comment: I confess that I did not understand the first comment of T.E.D. Now I see that we completely agree on the case. (And about the movie too. I read its description on Wikipedia, and I have no slightest desire to see it).